# Why does a conditional nested list comprehension return a list with a removed element?

Tags: python, list, nested, list-comprehension

**[Python]**

I have data in a nested list:

```
DATA_CONNS_MIN = [['T', '1', 'S', '2'], ['T', '10', 'S', '11'], ['S', '11', 'T', '11'], ['T', '5', 'S', '6'], ['B', '16', 'T', '9'], ['B', '16', 'T', '12'], ['T', '9', 'B', '17'], ['T', '12', 'B', '17'], ['B', '19', 'S', '4'], ['T', '3', 'S', '5'], ['T', '2', 'B', '19'], ['B', '19', 'S', '3'], ['T', '6', 'B', '22'], ['B', '22', 'S', '7'], ['B', '22', 'S', '8'], ['S', '6', 'B', '33'], ['S', '4', 'B', '33'], ['S', '7', 'T', '7'], ['S', '9', 'B', '16'], ['S', '8', 'B', '16'], ['S', '2', 'B', '30'], ['B', '30', 'T', '2'], ['B', '30', 'T', '14'], ['S', '3', 'B', '31'], ['B', '31', 'T', '3'], ['B', '31', 'T', '15'], ['S', '5', 'B', '32'], ['B', '32', 'T', '5'], ['B', '32', 'T', '16'], ['B', '33', 'T', '6'], ['B', '33', 'T', '17'], ['S', '10', 'B', '34'], ['B', '34', 'T', '10'], ['B', '34', 'T', '18'], ['S', '21', 'T', '21'], ['T', '17', 'S', '21'], ['S', '22', 'T', '22'], ['T', '18', 'S', '22'], ['B', '17', 'S', '10'], ['B', '34', 'T', '13'], ['T', '7', 'S', '9'], ['T', '11', 'S', '1'], ['T', '21', 'S', '1'], ['T', '14', 'S', '21'], ['T', '15', 'S', '21'], ['T', '16', 'S', '21'], ['T', '22', 'S', '10'], ['T', '13', 'S', '9']]
```

I have a list comprehension

```
DATA_CONNS_MIN = [x.remove(y) for x in DATA_CONNS_MIN for y in x if y[0] == 'B']
```

My output is:

```
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

I have attempted the list comprehension based on [this website](https://spapas.github.io/2016/04/27/python-nested-list-comprehensions/) and have tried having a look around StackOverflow with no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `x.remove()` returns `None`

Comment: You may find reading the documentation on [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) helpful. It looks like you're confounding list comprehensions with `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a spoiler:

```
DATA_CONNS_MIN = [x for x in DATA_CONNS_MIN  if x[0] != 'B']
```

It is easier to construct things than erase things, so here we are reconstructing the DATA_CONNS_MIN by only including its elements whose first element is not 'B'.